# Use tf.saved_model to predict multiple input vectors (tensorflow 2.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I trained an estimator object for prediction. But as you may know, `estimator.predict` restores parameters every time it runs, which is really slow. So I followed [this guide](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/serving-tensorflow-estimator.html) to speed it up. Since I'm using tensorflow 2.0, the `tf.contrib.predictor` API recommended in this guide is no longer available, so I resorted to the `saved_model` API which is the [official way](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) of loading models.

Here's the code for saving the estimator to a saved_model. (I only have 5 features for now)

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([tf.feature_column.numeric_column(str(x)) for x in range(1,6)]))
my_estimator.export_saved_model('saved_model',serving_input_fn)
```

output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Classify: None
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Regress: ['serving_default', 'regression']
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Predict: ['predict']
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Train: None
INFO:tensorflow:Signatures INCLUDED in export for Eval: None
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./output\model.ckpt-100000
INFO:tensorflow:Assets added to graph.
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to write.
INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: saved_model\temp-b'1579582279'\saved_model.pb
```

Following the [official guide for predicting](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators), I called the `predict` signature on `tf.Example` built with my input data:

```
example = tf.train.Example()
example.features.feature["1"].float_list.value.append(1) #note here the float_list.value can take multiple values
example.features.feature["2"].float_list.value.append(1)
example.features.feature["3"].float_list.value.append(1)
example.features.feature["4"].float_list.value.append(1)
example.features.feature["5"].float_list.value.append(1)
```

and make prediction with

```
my_model=tf.saved_model.load('saved_model/1579582279')
my_prediction=my_model.signatures["predict"](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))
```

While this works fine. When I construct `tf.example` with a list of values for each feature. And try to predict with the same code

```
example = tf.train.Example()
example.features.feature["1"].float_list.value.extend([1,2])
example.features.feature["2"].float_list.value.extend([1,2])
example.features.feature["3"].float_list.value.extend([1,2])
example.features.feature["4"].float_list.value.extend([1,2])
example.features.feature["5"].float_list.value.extend([1,2])
my_prediction=my_model.signatures["predict"](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))
```

It gives me error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Name: <unknown>, Key: 2, Index: 0.  Number of float values != expected.  Values size: 2 but output shape: [1]
     [[node ParseExample/ParseExample (defined at c:\users\i354164\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_pruned_2040]

Function call stack:
pruned
```

My question is: how to export/load the saved_model so that it can take `tf.Example` with more than one input?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to adjust the number of positional arguments after loading the model.

[how to input multi features for tensorflow model inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57457532/how-to-input-multi-features-for-tensorflow-model-inference)

```
infer._num_positional_args = 2
infer(tf.constant(x1), tf.constant(x2))
```